# Why is typeof needed?

Tags: c#

Something I've been thinking about from time to time: Why is the typeof operator needed in C#? Doesn't the compiler know that `public class Animal` is a type just by the very definition? Why do I need to specify `SomeMethod(typeof(Animal))` when I need to reference a type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typeof(Class)` is the only way to express Type as a literal. When you write `Class.SomeField` you mean static field. When you write `typeof(Class).SomeField` you reference field of object of class `Type` that represents your class.

Comment: Yes, but the question is: why?

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker why? to distinguish static members and type's members.

Comment: Ah, I see, missed that part of the answer, d'oh! +1

Answer (score 8):

`Animal` is simply the name of the type, `typeof(Animal`) returns the actual type object (`System.Type` instance). Sure, it may have been possibly just to have the type name returning the type object in code, but it makes the job a lot harder for the compiler/parser (recognising when a type name means typeof or something else) - hence the existence of the `typeof` keyword. It also arguably makes the code clearer to read.

Comment: You can also name properties like types (common for things like `Color` or so) which may confuse even more, then.

Comment: Indeed... it's asking the compiler to be really clever, for the purpose of shortening code marginally.

Comment: i believe the word we are looking for is 'ambiguity'. there are instances in which `someVariable.GetType () == Animal` may be ambiguous. is `Animal` in preceding snippet a class definition or member? if `typeof` is not used then `Animal` *must* be a member. if `typeof` is used then `Animal` *must* be a class definition.

Comment: Not sure it necessarily has to be ambiguous...at least in theory, but unclear, yes.

Comment: @Noldorin: See my answer for a contrived example of forced ambiguity.

Comment: Other languages, like Python don't require an operator and allow someone to parse a class simply by using the name. I dislike how `typeof` is necessary for classes and `GetType` is necessary for instances as it adds an inconstency

Answer (score 4):

Not having typeof does cause ambiguity:

```
class foo
{
    public static string ToString()
    {
        return "Static";
    }
}
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(foo).ToString());
    }
}
```

`foo` and `typeof(foo)` are not referring to the same thing, and forcing the compiler to pretend they are is a bad idea, even if we ignore this ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection for starters.  Many possibilities become available when you can inspect the type itself, instead of just having to know what it exposes, or that it exists at all.

Answer (score 0):

typeof() allows me to get an instance of a Type object without having to have an instance of the target object in hand.  This in turn lets me ask questions about the class without having an instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, how do you get the System.Type of a class without instantiating the class first, if you don't use the typeof operatore? Simple, you can't :D

Since you can do a lot of reflection stuff with just a System.Type, this operator is very handy.